# Extracting headers and footers (text repeated on every page) from documents

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm parsing pdf documents using various python libraries and can convert it to a list of pages (list of strings). I would like to automatically remove headers and footers, which are substrings that are repeated on *almost* every page (not necessary on every page). I don't want to rely too much on geometry (such as looking at fixed positions). Assume no metadata is available.

I'm aware of `difflib.SequenceMatcher` class and similar tools, but that mostly works on a **pair** of strings. But I want to leverage the fact that the document has many pages, not just do pair-wise comparisons.

I'm interested both in an efficient algorithm as well as in possible python tools, if there are any. Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python library `PyMuPDF` which might help you with your problem. First of all it does not knows anything about headers and footers, but you can extract a lot of metadata dictionary from it and analyze it. I had same problem where I wanted to extract only headers of the pdf file for every page. I used this metadata which contained information about text like font size and font name. In my case, every header title had font size bigger compared to other texts on the same page, so I used that information for extraction.

Comment: Thank you, @Sharmiko, this might be useful sometimes, but I'm mostly talking about scanned documents that just contain images and an ocr-ed (invisible) text layer. The font information might depend on the OCR-quality and configuration, but I wouldn't rely on ti too much. And I'm really kind of interested in an algorithm that, from 100 pages, finds "most often repeated chunks". However, for "digital" pdf's, your suggestion will be definitely useful.